# Multiple user entries for multiple client data recorded in single table. how to transform SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms

I'm trying to query my data which records multiple user entries for multiple client data in a single table distinguished by a unique group activity id.

Please see my table and intended output.

[image: table and intended view cheers!]

Comment: Could you provide the basic table layout and perhaps a bit of the data you are talking about?

Comment: Interesting ... Is there anything else that distinguishes a 'user' from a 'client other than the value in the activityParticipant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me as though you simply want all combinations of participants that are 'Users' with participants that are 'Clients' ...

```
-- Prep Work
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table

SELECT * INTO #Table FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'Client A'),
    (2, 'Client B'),
    (3, 'Client C'),
    (12, 'User A'),
    (12, 'User B'),
    (12, 'User C'),
    (12, 'User D')
) S(activityId, activityParticipant)
```

Try this query against 'your' table ....

```
-- Actual Query
SELECT
    U.activityParticipant,
    C.activityParticipant
FROM
    (SELECT activityParticipant FROM #Table WHERE activityParticipant LIKE 'User%') U
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT activityParticipant FROM #Table WHERE activityParticipant LIKE 'Client%') C
ORDER BY
    U.activityParticipant,
    C.activityParticipant
```

Comment: wow this just opened me to a new world of sql queries. Cheers Thanks Jason!!

Comment: Thanks @KeithLee! Glad you found it useful.